# How to update several values in row in matlab's dataset?

Tags: matlab, dataset

I have a **46x46** dataset and I need to update several values in single row.

For example:

```
data =   
A B C D  
0 0 0 0  
0 0 0 0  
0 0 0 0
```

I want to make it like

```
A B C D  
0 0 0 0  
0 1 0 1  
0 0 0 0
```

Can I write something like this:

```
data(2, ['B', 'D']) = [1, 1];
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes:

```
data(2, [2 4]) = mat2dataset([1 1]);
```

or simply:

```
data(2, [2 4]) = mat2dataset(1);
```

> NB: As a side note, you should avoid using datasets. According to the
>   documentation: "The dataset data type might be removed in a future
>   release. To work with heterogeneous data, use the Matlab table data
>   type instead."

Comment: Thank you so much!)
Hadn't figured it out))

Answer (score 0):

If you have a [**`table`**](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/tables.html) (which is the recommended replacement of the [`dataset`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/stats/dataset.html) type), you can refer to the names of the columns using the `'VariableNames'` property:

First build the table: define the column names and fill all columns with zeros:

```
data = table(zeros(3,1), zeros(3,1), zeros(3,1), zeros(3,1), ....
       'VariableNames', {'A','B','C','D'});
```

This gives

```
data = 
    A    B    C    D
    _    _    _    _
    0    0    0    0
    0    0    0    0
    0    0    0    0
```

Then, to change the entries as in your question entries, you can use

```
data(2, ismember(data.Properties.VariableNames, {'B' 'D'})) = {1, 1};
```

or

```
data(2, ismember(data.Properties.VariableNames, {'B' 'D'})) = deal({1});
```

or more directly

```
data.B(2) = 1;
data.D(2) = 1;
```

Either of the above gives

```
data = 
    A    B    C    D
    _    _    _    _
    0    0    0    0
    0    1    0    1
    0    0    0    0
```

Comment: He/she doesn't have a _Table_, but a _dataset_.

Comment: @Crazyrat Hm. True. I never used `dataset` type, and thought it was a generic name :-) Anyway, since the `dataset` is obsolete an it is recommended to use `table` instead, I think I'll leave the answer, as it may be useful